# Access data attributes from dropzone.js parameters - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, parameters, dropzone.js

I'm trying to access at data parameters from dropzoneOption as below:

```
data() {
  return {
    e1: 0,
    dropzoneOptions: {
      url: '/api/imageUpload',
      thumbnailWidth: null,
      thumbnailHeight: null,
      acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png',
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      previewsContainer: '.preview-container',
      init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
          //Access to e1 params.
          //This.e1 not working
      });
      },
    }
  }
},
```

Is there any way to access it from inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried writing it like:

```js
init: function () {
 const _this = this //assigning this as a variable
  this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
     console.log("Added file ", file); 
     console.log(_this.e1)
  });
}
```

You could also hook into a dropzone event:

```js
    
[...]
fileAdded: {
    sendingEvent (file) {
      // access this.e1 here
    }
  }
```

```html
<vue-dropzone v-on:vdropzone-file-added="fileAdded"></vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: Resolved using @vdropzone-file-added="filedAdded" and declaring a method called filledAdded. Thank You!